# Error when iterating through array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Hey guys im trying to run through an array of checkboxes to add up a price and keep getting an unexpected } error and i cant figure out why:

```
            $price;
        foreach($_POST['extras'] as $extra)
            {
            if($extra == "Deodoriser"){
                        $price = $price + 10;
                    } elseif($extra == "Carpet Protector (5 litre)"){
                        $price = $price + 20
                    } elseif($extra == "Carpet Repair Tools"){
                        $price = $price + 30
                    } elseif($extra == "Furniture Moving Equipment"){
                        $price = $price + 40
                    } elseif($extra == "Furniture Tabs"){
                        $price = $price + 50
                    } elseif($extra == "Urine Decontamination Treatment"){
                        $price = $price + 60 }
            }
```

I now get this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /home/fevsdiet/public_html/diycarpetcare.co.uk/booking/booking.event.processing.php on line 45

Comment: You're missing the last `}` for the `foreach`. It can be seen clearly!

Comment: @wesley van Opdorp You were correct, now however i get this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /home/fevsdiet/public_html/diycarpetcare.co.uk/booking/booking.event.processing.php on line 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($extra == "Deodoriser"){ 
    $price = $price + 10; 
} elseif($extra == "Carpet Protector (5 litre)") { 
    $price = $price + 20; 
} elseif($extra == "Carpet Repair Tools") { 
    $price = $price + 30; 
} elseif($extra == "Furniture Moving Equipment") {
    $price = $price + 40; 
} elseif($extra == "Furniture Tabs") {
    $price = $price + 50;
} elseif($extra == "Urine Decontamination Treatment") {
    $price = $price + 60;
} else {
    $price = 0;
}
```

Alternative:

```
foreach($_POST['extras'] as $extra) {
    switch($extra) {
        case 'Deodoriser':
            $price = $price + 10;
            break;
        case 'Carpet Protector (5 litre)':
            $price = $price + 20;
            break;
        case 'Carpet Repair Tools':
            $price = $price + 30;
            break;
        case 'Furniture Moving Equipment':
            $price = $price + 40;
            break;
        case 'Furniture Tabs':
            $price = $price + 50;
            break;
        case 'Urine Decontamination Treatment':
            $price = $price + 60;
            break;
        // Could add a default as well
        default:
            $price = 0;
    }
}
```